# Difficulty loading Word HTML file via file_get_contents

Tags: php, unicode, ms-word

I convert Word Documents to html for display.  I use [DocTo](https://github.com/tobya/docto) to convert from .doc to .html.

If I open the resulting html file in a browser it is displayed correctly without any ? or other unicode problems.

However for my website I have to retrieve the HTML file via

```
file_get_contents('file/url to my file.html');
```

The resulting html when displayed has ? and [] squares in place of some characters in the document.

Is there a simple workaround I'm missing?

I know I could link directly to the html file, however this does not suit my needs as I need to output the content inside a div.

Comment: encode everything in UTF-8

Comment: Can you check if your PHP file is encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Specify the character encoding for the HTML document: `<head> <meta charset="UTF-8"></head>`